# Can I use one tag from Tag Manager on multiple domains?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I found similar question, but it's not the same.

I have a client that has multiple domains:

onedomain.com

twodomain.com

and 20 more

I have set up Google Analytics accounts for each domain. So i have one code for onedomain.com, second code for twodomain.com and so on.

Now i would like to have one Google Tag set up on every domain client has and than in Google Tag management system set it up like this:

- if it is onedomain, load GA code for onedomain
- if it is twodomain, load GA code for twodomain

etc.

Now, can i set it up like this in Google Tag Manager, or i need to set up new Google Tag for each of my clients domains?

PS. I am NOT interested in cross-domain tracking etc. I want separate GA codes for every domain, but one Google Tag for all domains, and question is, if i can differentiate codes loaded based on domain Google Tag is loaded on.

Comment: @nyuen thanks you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. You'll just need to create a Look-up Table to help you switch GA accounts, based on the hostname. Be careful with your nomenclature though - "separate GA code" - do you mean Javascript code, or GA account? The JS that loads the analytics library is the same. The GA account is different.